# Can I declare a password/key through parameters in windows scheduler?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am running few scripts in powershell and cmd through windows scheduler. I have to provide my credentials and access keys in both the cmd and powershell scripts.

Is there anyway where I can provide my credentials through parameters like in Continous integration Tools? or any other way?

ex:

```
        SET Username=Usrnme
        Set Password=pswd //shouldn't be visible
     curl.exe --basic --u usrnme:pswd -X get "https:www.google.com" -k
```

I don't want everybody who has access to the system to view the username and password.

Please suggest.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. The title says "Can I encrypt" and your text body asks if you can provide credentials through a parameter. Try to refine your question and provide an example of your attempts or problem to get a good answer

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options:

1. Put the user name and password in a file and read it into batch script variables using `for /f` command
2. If you not using "simple filesharing" (= home edition  versions of windows) you can set security so only one specific user has access to a password file or leave it in batch script and make that file's security so only one specific user has access.
3. Any text you are passing on a `curl` command line it is visible to any process while your curl.exe process is running. Another task can list running tasks eg from command prompt `wmic process where ^(name^="curl.exe"^) get commandline` would show it. I don't know how to obscure that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Powershell Credential Manager](https://github.com/davotronic5000/PowerShell_Credential_Manager) to safely store the password on local computer. Then you can add the parameter to the script that represents credential target. See the example [here](https://github.com/majkinetor/posh/blob/master/MM_TFS/MM_TFS.psm1#L20)